# Rails: time_select helper validation on previous given time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, time, simple-form

I would like to know if there is a built-in functionality of rails `time_select`, that handles the valid range of my end_time.

I have `start_time` and `end_time`. `end_time` is not allowed to be "smaller" than `start_time`.

```
<%= f.time_select :start_time, {minute_step: 15}%>
```

How can I realize this?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Is `start_time` already defined here, or are they both created from the same form?

Comment: start_time and end_time are both in one form and have a default range of 0:00 to 23:00 with 15 minutes steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you can't specify range via `time_select`. The option is to cut `end_time` range using javascript based on `start_time` value and add custom validation for reliability: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods.

```
def end_time_validity
  if end_time < start_time
    errors.add(:end_time, "can't be before start time")
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try to just "hide" them with custom javascript. I hoped rails had an elegant way to handle this out of the box :)